# What does ':' colon mark means in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, regexp-replace

```
 if (:new.first_name is not null) then
       :new.first_name := substr(regexp_replace(:new.first_name,'[^'||chr(1)||'-'||chr(127)||']',null),1,20);
    end if;
```

can someone help me with this code? I cannot understand it!

Comment: `:new` probably is referring to the newly inserted/updated row, as this code is probably executing inside some sort of trigger.  Check the documentation for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is likely from an UPDATE or INSERT trigger, it refers to a pseudo row containing the new values for the row

```
UPDATE x
SET y = 'z'
WHERE y = 'a'
```

A trigger on this update would have an `:old` pseudorow where column `y` is `'a'` and a `:new` pseudorow where `y` is `'z'`. If you modify the value of the `:new` in a `before` trigger, it will change what is written to the table

Comment: Also i would like to add another use, since the question its about the ":", this can be use for **user-input variables** too, if you're using SQL Developer. To let the user enter the values needed for each variable every time you execute some code.